# Laravel - Hasher / Reset password issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hash

I have traced the reset password issue back to the hasher method within the DatabaseTokenRepository.

When it compares the two token hashes (The one it gets from the user's reset request and the one from the database) it fails, no matter what. I've tried plainly copy pasting from the database and compare the two strings that way, yet it still returns false.

I am using Laravel **5.4**

**User's token** (From the reset email)

```
"$2y$10$xAnDTr6/G41sAROp4h76hOhx7c4Ily4eYBtFc1J4voCgwIRhq9Mge"
```

**Database Token**

```
"$2y$10$xAnDTr6/G41sAROp4h76hOhx7c4Ily4eYBtFc1J4voCgwIRhq9Mge"
```

Return of the hasher function is still **false**.

Code from the **DatabaseTokenRepository**

```
public function exists(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token)
{
    $record = (array) $this->getTable()->where(
        'email', $user->getEmailForPasswordReset()
    )->first();

    //dump($token);
    //dump($record['token']);
    //dd($this->hasher->check($token, $record['token']));

    return $record &&
           ! $this->tokenExpired($record['created_at']) &&
             $this->hasher->check($token, $record['token']);
}
```

**Edit:**
Using `hash_equals($token, $record['token']);` returns true, however that is not a solution (Since this is the source files, and an update to these files would break my function)

Comment: When you say the user's token is what you're supplying. Is that true? that's already hashed.

Comment: It is supposed to be hashed, it's how Laravel handles password resets. You use the hashed string in a GET route, like '/password/reset/{token}' and it then verifies that it is the same hash within the database and lets you change the password - however since it's using password_verify to compare hashes it fails (As it expects a non-hashed value). This is what I want to circumvent without changing source files. @apokryfos

Comment: No it's not. `$hasher->check` internally uses [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) which accepts the unhashed value as the first parameter and compares it against the hash. It also makes little sense to hash anything if you're transmitting the actual hash to the user.

Comment: Well, I am using the out-of-the-box solution which Laravel comes with? So I don't see how it's not supposed to be hashed, when that's what it shoots at me within the email? It does make sense to transmit a hash, when you need to compare said hash only with the hash in the database. The hash itself contains no data at all, it just contains 40 random letters and a hash key, as defined in DatabaseTokenRepository.

Comment: What's even more bizarre is that that the user's token seems to be a bcrypt hashed value while the `DatabaseTokenRepository` generates new hashes using `hash_hmac` which does not have the `$2$10$` prefix

Comment: I found the issue, it was stupidity and blind sight from my side. I looked into what you said a bit more, and the reason for it not working was because I used the already hashed token when sending the email, instead of sending the unhashed token over to the email via the construct - which resulted in the password_verify failing.

I looked into the bizarre thing you mentioned, and that seems to be because it hash_hmac's the key, and THEN it bcrypts that hash.

However problem solved, thanks to your insight. Thank you!

Comment: When you're able to can you answer your question with some more detail of that the problem was and how you solved it?  This sounds like something that might help other people too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up, instead of using the intended hash_hmac hash I used the one from the database which is hashed twice - which resulted in it failing everytime because the password_verify function requires the value and not the hash.

To anybody with the same issue, I advice you look into what you're emailing the user, this is where I messed up by grabbing the token from the database instead of passing it around with controllers.